# Xml a html automatico en servidor

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, cron

resulta que en mi servidor linux ubuntu resulta que un archivo de salida de un módulo que es en formato xml lo está convirtiendo directamente a formato html, por lo que la salida cron hace que donde se reciba esos datos ponga que el formato xml es incorrecto, quería saber si es que existe algo que esté provocando esto, se puede modificar algún parámetro del servidor para que no haga esto?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, tendrías que ser un poco mas especifico, revisa el código del modulo para ver cual es su proceso.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: mas contexto, para poder responder, que modulo, es un programa un script etc? xml y html no son los mismo,es como que hables de que el archivo resultado es pdf y quieres convertirlo a jpg, no tienen sentido